# How to use protoc to generate json represents of descriptor?

Tags: javascript, json, go, protocol-buffers, protoc

Tring to `*.proto` -> json -generator-> other things

Tried [pbjs](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/tree/master/cli), but the json can only hold one option, and no comment.

Is there any way to use the protoc to generate the json that represent the protos ?

Write a protoc generator is harder than work with the json.

**EDIT**

For example

With a proto like [this](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/90afe4412de8070b0c0681e5905a6e0213072a85/tests/data/test.proto)

```
syntax = "proto2";

option java_package = "com.google.apps.jspb.proto";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package jspb.test;

message Empty {
}

enum OuterEnum {
  FOO = 1;
  BAR = 2;
}

message EnumContainer {
  optional OuterEnum outer_enum = 1;
}

message Simple1 {
  required string a_string = 1;
  repeated string a_repeated_string = 2;
  optional bool a_boolean = 3;
}
// etc etc
```

pbjs can generate a json that represent the proto def like [this](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/90afe4412de8070b0c0681e5905a6e0213072a85/tests/data/test.json)

```json
{
  "options": {
    "java_package": "com.google.apps.jspb.proto",
    "java_multiple_files": true
  },
  "nested": {
    "jspb": {
      "nested": {
        "test": {
          "nested": {
            "Empty": {
              "fields": {}
            },
            "OuterEnum": {
              "values": {
                "FOO": 1,
                "BAR": 2
              }
            },
            "EnumContainer": {
              "fields": {
                "outerEnum": {
                  "type": "OuterEnum",
                  "id": 1
                }
              }
            },
            "Simple1": {
              "fields": {
                "aString": {
                  "rule": "required",
                  "type": "string",
                  "id": 1
                },
                "aRepeatedString": {
                  "rule": "repeated",
                  "type": "string",
                  "id": 2
                },
                "aBoolean": {
                  "type": "bool",
                  "id": 3
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I can work with the json instead of protoc & proto.
But pbjs is unmaintained, has a lot problem, trying to get these from protoc.

**UPDATE**

Seems what I want is the [descriptor](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto), just need a way to get the descriptor data out of protoc.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? (perhaps show a simple `.proto` file and the JSON output you are expecting). Are you trying to use `protoc` to generate code that will convert protobuf encoded data into JSON? If so `protoc` will generate code that helps with this, but you would need to write a bit of code to load the data and output as JSON (e.g. in go that might mean using [protojson](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.1/encoding/protojson)).

Answer (score 0):

protoc support `-o` to output descriptor set in binary format, almost include everything.

---

Problem solved by making [protoc-gen-debug](https://github.com/lyft/protoc-gen-star/tree/master/protoc-gen-debug) write the request as a json file, so I get a parsed proto descriptor as json.